# CentOS7 sets time to +8h in the night: [systemd] Time has been changed

Tags: centos, centos7, systemd

I am curious: My CentOS7 server, which did not run ntpd or chrony, updated the system's time to +8h at 11pm.

Message:

```
[systemd] Time has been changed
```

appears in `/var/log/messages`.

Well: I don't know what is happening here. As ntpd and chrony are not running, I do not know what to check next.

Comment: Please answer your own question, which is encouraged.   https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The problem was an incorrect time on the VMWare hypervisor. On every Veeam-backup-run the VM got the faulty time information, as the VMware-tools fetched the wrong time from the ESXi.